# Setting up lan and also SVN server

Tags: svn, local-area-network

I have to set up a LAN connection between 5 laptops, 2 using windows 7 and other 2 using windows xp and 1 using Ubuntu. I have installed VisualSVN. Now How do other people update their code to my laptop which is the central svn repository. They are using eclipse and dreamweaver IDE for development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab TortoiseSVN and set it up in 5 min per machine.

Comment: Yeah, that'll work fine in ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

VisualSVN is a subversion client. You need to install (unless it's already installed of course) the subversion server. You also need to configure it to allow access to the repository for the other computers on your LAN.

[Chapter 6](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.html) in Version Control with Subversion is a good place to start

There are also tons of information if you just search for it.

This one's pretty good: [Setup a Subversion Server in 4 Minutes](http://www.tonyspencer.com/2007/03/02/setup-a-subversion-server-in-4-minutes/)

Comment: VisualSVN Server is also a good subversion+apache package for windows  http://www.visualsvn.com/server/ - not sure if your 'server' is the ubuntu laptop or not...

Comment: @BoyMars, Thanks, I didn't know that! Now, if he has VisualSVN Server, how would you configure that? I have no clue.

Answer (score 2):

I know you have installed VisualSVN i have read it. But for your situation **[Git](http://git-scm.com/)** sounds much better.

SVN has a lot of overhead and put in every folder an .svn folder. With Git you have a decentral version control. With so many clients its very cool. Perhaps its a solution.